# Option to remove resource from Terraform state instead of destroying them?

Tags: terraform

In Terraform, is it possible to mark objects that should live on outside of the Terraform state rather than be destroyed as part of an `apply`? If so, how?

For example, I don't mind if stale Elastic Beanstalk or AWS Lambda bundles sit in S3. In fact, I might prefer to keep them.

Comment: If you only want Create operations for a resource and do not want manage the resource, then you can remove the resource from the config and state afterwards.

Comment: May be a combination of `prevent_destroy` & `ignore_changes` part of [lifecycle arguments](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle) will do this?

Comment: But `prevent_destroy` will error when `terraform destroy` is issued. maybe those resources you don't want to delete can be part of another state file.

Answer (score 4):

Try to remove them manually with the following

```
terraform state rm aws_s3_bucket.bucket
```

See here https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/state/rm

Beware:
Removing resources from your state will add them again, if you keep the resources within your terraform files. Instead of using those as resource, change them to use data sources. Most of the resources provides also an equivalent as data sources, e.g.

S3 resource:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket

S3 data source:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/s3_bucket